# How Do I Disable Remote Management and Enable Screen Sharing?

Tags: macos, ssh, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I am connected to a headless remote Mac Mini. Under Sharing in the System Preferences both **Remote Login** and **Remote Management** are checked though **Remote Mangement** is "grayed out". I would like to disable **Remote Management** and enable **Screen Sharing**.

Currently the **Screen Sharing** checkbox is "grayed out". When I click on it, I get the following message: "Screen Sharing is currently being controlled by the Remote Management service." This warning to not continue makes sense if I would lose my current VNC connection and not be able to turn it back on remotely.

To access the remote server I Connect to Server (command-k) vnc://IPnumber

I would like just **Remote Login** and **Screen Sharing** enabled and **Remote Management** disabled.

Does anyone know the steps for me to accomplish this goal remotely?

Comment: You will lose your VNC connection immediately if you toggle off Remote Management. If only `systemsetup` allowed you to toggle these settings, this would be a one line ssh command. What version of OS is running on the remote Mac and do you perhaps have a Mac you can control that runs the same version of the OS?

Answer (score 3):

I found the following code in a file I didn't open for a long time. It enables Remote Login on a remote device. Save the script somewhere (from now on referred to as `/path/to/script/`). Copy the script to the other device.

```
tell application "System Preferences" to set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.sharing"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 1 of row 6 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing"
end tell
```

This enables remote login. Now, to disable remote management and enable screen sharing, use the same script, but remove the 3rd line and add these 2 lines:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to set current pane to pane "com.apple.preferences.sharing"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 1 of row 7 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing"
    click checkbox 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing"
end tell
```

To copy this script on the remote device, use `scp` (secure copy). To use `scp` type
`scp /path/to/script username@IP.of.other.device:/some/path`
OR
`scp username@hostnameOfDevice:/some/path/`
The second option (using the device hostname) requires that the devices are on a computer-to-computer network, so it will not work on a normal wifi network. You will see a prompt requesting the password of `username`. When you type the password, you will not see any text appear (obviously to prevent people from seeing the password).

Once it is copied, remotely log into the device:
`ssh username@IP.of.other.device`
OR
`ssh username@hostnameOfDevice`
Again, the use of the hostname requires computer-to-computer network. Once logged in, run the script using `osascript /some/path/theScript.scpt` (remember that using `scp` we copied the script to `/some/path`, this will be different on your device). This will disable remote management and enable screen sharing.
Good luck!

Comment: Good idea. On OS 11 at least, the numbers need to be one less (row 6 and row 1).